# Adding new <select> tag by clicking on the button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a "Add a statement" button, and I need a `<select>` tag to appear on my page every time after clicking the button (without refreshing the page). Here's the code of Select:

```
<select id = "statement" name = "statement">
<?php

   $select = "SELECT name FROM Statements";
   $res = $conn->query($select);
   while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()){
       echo "<option value=\"" . $row['name'] . "\">" . $row['name'] . "</option>";
   }

?>
</select>
```

How can I do that?

Comment: a new select or a new option in the select?

Comment: @CodeiSir a new select.

Comment: with what content? a copy of it?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/clone http://api.jquery.com/append

Comment: @CodeiSir yes, with the same code that I posted: user clicks on a button, select tag appears, and he choses a statement from a same list every time (which is selected from a database).

Comment: And what have you tryed so far?

Comment: @CodeiSir I've written a php function, that adds a new select tag, and I was trying to call that function by clicking on the button, but I guess that wasn't a good idea

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I found that you don't need jQuery for this.

Comment: @user5718409 Did you see my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ELEMENT.cloneNode(true)` to clone the Element, and `true` to also clone the Child nodes:

```js
var selectionCounter = 0
function cloneSelect() {
  var select = document.getElementById("statement")
  var clone = select.cloneNode(true)
  var name = select.getAttribute("name") + selectionCounter++
  clone.id = name
  clone.setAttribute("name", name)
  document.getElementById("selectContainer").appendChild(clone)
}
```

```html
<div id="selectContainer">
  <select id="statement" name="statement">
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
  </select>
</div>

<button onclick="cloneSelect()">Add another Select</button>
```

More Information about `node.cloneNode(deep)` here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I guess I also need to change select's name from "statement" to "statement_n", so I could get the selected option value, don't I?

Comment: I added the code to do so, the new ones will be named "statement0" , "statement1", ...

Comment: @user5718409 does it work for you now? Do you need any more help?

Answer (score -1):

I think it will help you-

```
<script>
   function addOption(){
   var sel = document.getElementById("statement");
   var option = document.createElement("option");
   option.innerHTML = "name";
   option.value = "1";
   sel.appendChild(option);
}
</script>
```

Comment: "a new select or a new option in the select? – CodeiSir 1 hour ago"   
   
   
"@CodeiSir a new select. – user5718409"

Comment: A new option will be created inside the select.

Comment: he wants a new select not a new option

Comment: see my new answer, I think it is whatever you want to do.

Answer (score -1):

Try this. It may help you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>

<body>
<div id="container"></div>
<button type="button" id="add" onclick="addOption()">Add a statement</button>

<?php

$que = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM Statements") or die(mysql_error());

$script = "<script>function addOption(){";
$script .= "var container = document.getElementById('container');";
$script .= "var select = document.createElement('select');";
while($data = mysql_fetch_array($que)){
$script .= "var option = document.createElement('option');";
  $script .= "option.innerHTML = '$data[0]';";
  $script .= "select.appendChild(option);";
}
$script .= "container.appendChild(select);";
$script .= "}</script>";
echo $script;
?>



</body>

</html>
```